# Подсветка выбранного пункта меню

Tags: html, css

Как подсветить какой пункт в меню выбран?

Обновлю вопрос, поскольку не нашел ответа.

[image]

Вот что мне надо! И прошу, не надо писать, что на каждой странице надо вручную переделывать меню.

Comment: Что за "Пункт меню? Приведите исходный код или опишите вопрос поподробнее

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно сделать с помощью jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('document').ready(function() {
    $('.menu a').each(function() {
        if ('http://site.ru'+$(this).attr('href') == window.location.href)
        {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
}); 
 </script>
```

Добавить класс menu в любое меню на странице(их даже может быть не сколько)
и соответственно прописать стили для класса active

**Так же вариант в php**

```
<?php foreach($result as $item): ?>
<a href="/link.php?menu=<?php echo $item['id']; ?>" <?php if($_GET['menu'] == $item['id']) {echo "class='active'";} ?>><?php echo $item['name']; ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: а будет ли работать с динамично создаваемыми ссылками? Начало всегда одно, например search.php, а затем к нему плюсуется номер сессии и другое.

Comment: Какая бы страница не была, jquery подсветит её, и не нужно заморачиваться с лишний кодом, юзайте jquery, и добавляйте класс menu(можете изменить) во все блоки меню.

Comment: О да, все отлично! Но есть небольшой вопрос, как задать класс для <li> вместо ссылки, если ссылка находится внутри <li>?

Comment: разницы нету где ссылка находиться хоть в <li><span><a href="/">ссылка</a></span></li> , селектор $('.menu a') выделяет абсолютна все ссылки класса menu

Answer (score 5):

Дописываете class к пункту и пишете ему css свойства выбранного элемента (тут уже на ваше усмотрение изменить цвет, подчеркнуть и т.д.)

**Добавлено из комментария**.

html:

```
<a href="">link1</a>  
<a href="">link2</a>  
<a href="" class="active">link3</a>  
<a href="">link4</a>
```

css:

```
.active{  
    color:#f00;  
}
```

Comment: Можно пример кода?

Comment: Перенесено в ответ.

Comment: Нет это статичный код. Я совсем не это имел ввиду, нужен скрипт что бы выделял так последний нажатый пункт после перехода на страницу, делать так на каждой странице - смешно.

Comment: А что мешает дописывать класс в зависимости от id страницы еще на этапе формирования кода страницы?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, вы это имеете в виду (тень):

```
 box-shadow:3px 3px #FFFFFF 15px;
```

Answer (score 1):

> О да, все отлично! Но есть небольшой вопрос, как задать класс для <li> вместо ссылки, если ссылка находится внутри <li>?

Если ссылка <a...> лежит непосредственно в <li>, то можно так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('document').ready(function() {
    $('.menu a').each(function() {
      if ('http://site.ru'+$(this).attr('href') == window.location.href)
      {
        $(this).parenrt().addClass('active');
      }
    });
  }); 
</script>
```

То есть класс "active" присвоить родительскому элементу.

Comment: а если по структуре меню - ><div class="menu"> <ul> <li> <a href=.....> <закрывающие теги> и надо присвоить класс тегу <li>, а не ссылке?